# How to test UserDefauls "AppleLanguages" and "AppleLocale" when running from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to add an option to my app that allows the user to switch between available languages. To achieve this I found several information about the `UserDefaults` keys `AppleLanguages` and `AppleLocale`. While setting/updating these settings when running the app directly works fine, it does not have any effect when running the app from Xcode.

I assume this related to the Xcode feature to launch an app with a specific language / local specified in the scheme settings? However, although I have selected the "Use System Language" and "Use System Region" settings here, `AppleLanguages` and `AppleLocale` still do not have any effect.

This makes testing quite hard.

**TL;DR:** Can `AppleLanguages` and `AppleLocale` also be tested when running an app from Xcode?

Comment: FYI - there's no reason to add a feature to your app to let the user change languages. iOS already allows a user to do this in the app-specific settings page. At least this was added in iOS 16 (not sure if it's in iOS 15 or not).

Comment: @HangRash This is correct, but I get surprisingly many support questions asking how to switch the language. While I wonder myself why to switch the language in the first place, this does not really matter, does it? It seems that this is a feature many users need and many users do not know about the system settings. So I can either teach users that their requirement does not make sense from my point of view or I can give them an easy way to get the desired result by moving the system feature into my app settings. Why shouldn't I do this?